# Postman and HttpWebRequest are giving different results

Tags: c#, httprequest, httpresponse, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm new to C# and I want to send a request in JSON to an API and get the JSON response in return so that I can use it in my application. But every time I am making the request, I am getting a 404 error. When I do the Postman Request using the same data for POST, I am getting a positive result.

Below is the JSON I'm sending to the API using Postman.

```
{
  "ActionId": null,
  "AgentCode": "MerchantCode:Password",
  "Mpin": null,
  "Amount": 0.0,
  "CustomerMSISDN": null,
  "ServiceId": 0,
  "MTI": "0300",
  "TerminalId": null,
  "TransactionRef": null,
  "CustomerAccount": null,
  "CustomerData": null,
  "Product": null,
  "ServiceProvider": "Yomoney",
  "Source": null,
  "PaymentMethod": null,
  "ProcessingCode": "420000",
  "Quantity": null,
  "OrderLines": null,
  "Narrative": null,
  "Note": null,
  "MaxSale": 0.0,
  "MinSale": 0.0,
  "TransactionType": 2
}
```

and this is the URL I am sending to:

```
https://www.yomoneyservice.com/yoclient/transaction
```

and this is the response I get

```
{"ResponseCode":"00000","Description":null,"Balance":null,"TransactionCode":null,"vouchers":null,"AgentCode":null,"Mpin":null,"Amount":0,"MaxSale":0,"MinSale":0,"CustomerMSISDN":null,"ServiceId":0,"MTI":null,"TerminalId":null,"TransactionRef":null,"TransactionType":0,"CustomerAccount":null,"CustomerData":null,"Product":null,"Quantity":0,"Action":null,"ProcessingCode":null,"Note":"Purchase","Narrative":"[{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"THE
REDEEMED
SOLDIER\",\"Value\":\"12\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":12,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"BUY
VOUCHER\",\"Value\":\"10\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":\"~/Content/Logos/YOMONEY/yomoney_v_logo.png\",\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":10,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ECONET
PINLLESS\",\"Value\":\"8\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":\"~/Content/Logos/YOMONEY/buddie.png\",\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":8,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"TELECEL
PINLESS\",\"Value\":\"3\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":3,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Econet\",\"Value\":\"2\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":2,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":true,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"NETONE
PINLESS\",\"Value\":\"1\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":1,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"THE
REDEEMED
SOLDIER\",\"Value\":\"12\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":12,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"BUY
VOUCHER\",\"Value\":\"10\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":\"~/Content/Logos/YOMONEY/yomoney_v_logo.png\",\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":10,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ECONET
PINLLESS\",\"Value\":\"8\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":\"~/Content/Logos/YOMONEY/buddie.png\",\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":8,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"TELECEL
PINLESS\",\"Value\":\"3\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":3,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Econet\",\"Value\":\"2\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":2,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":true,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false},{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"NETONE
PINLESS\",\"Value\":\"1\",\"Note\":\"Supplier\",\"Image\":null,\"Description\":null,\"Section\":null,\"ServiceId\":1,\"Currency\":null,\"ActionId\":1,\"TransactionType\":0,\"SupplierId\":null,\"Amount\":null,\"Count\":0,\"date\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"WebLink\":null,\"HasProducts\":false,\"IsAdvert\":false,\"IsNotAdvert\":false,\"IsShare\":false,\"RequireVerification\":false,\"RequiresRegistration\":false,\"RequiresAmount\":false}]"}
```

Now, In C# I'm using WebRequest&WebResponse but I'm getting a 404 error saying "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.". Below is my C# code

```
try
            {
                string url = String.Format("https://www.yomoneyservice.com/yoclient/transaction");
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";                        
                
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yomoneyRequest, Formatting.Indented);

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        yomoneyResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YomoneyResponse>(result);
                    }
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
```

I'm no longer sure where I'm getting it wrong in my C# code, could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your use case both in code and postman. Your observation is correct, it works in postman but not in C# code.

Then I observe the different between the requests being sent from code and postman. The difference is cookie.

Postman sends one cookie with name "AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport" which has value "1".

Then I modified your code to add cookie also while sending the request to API, and it worked fine.

To add cookie to HttpWebRequest, you need to use [CookieContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer?view=netcore-3.1).

You need to initialize `CookiContainer` property of httpWebRequest and add cookie to it.

You need to change your code as following.

```
try
{

    string url = String.Format("https://www.yomoneyservice.com/yoclient/transaction");
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST"; 
    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    Cookie c = new Cookie("AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport", "1");
    c.Domain = "www.yomoneyservice.com";
    httpWebRequest.CookieContainer.Add(c);  
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yomoneyRequest, Formatting.Indented);
    
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        var yomoneyResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YomoneyResponse>(result);
    } 
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I hope this will help you resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you so much. Your solution worked just fine! I would have never thought about the cookie.